# email ID availablity check using ajax and codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to validate email Availability using Codeigniter and ajax.. but nothing works.

I am following this tutorial form youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwFxMxUAsPs&t).

here is my code

**signup.php - view**

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" id="email">
</div>
<div class="text-muted font-italic"><small><span class="font-weight-700" id="email_result" name="email_result">fake</span></small></div>
```

**ajax call**

```
 $('#email').change(function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    if (email != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/check_email_availability",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                email: email
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#email_result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**pages.php - controller**

```
<?php
    class Pages extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function view($page = 'signup')
        {
            if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
               show_404();
            }
    
            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
    
            $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
       }

      function check_email_availability()
      {
    
         $this->load->model("check_email_model");
          if ($this->check_email_model->is_email_available($_POST["email"])) {
             echo 'Email Already register';
          } else {
             echo 'Email Available';
          }
      }
  }
```

**check_email_model.php - model**

```
<?php
class Check_email_model extends CI_Model
{
   function is_email_available($email)
   {
      $this->db->where('email', $email);
      $query = $this->db->get('hospital');
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Solved - solution - as i said i am new to codeigniter so i forgot to autoload database library